# Azure Databricks - Resolve : User does not have permission SELECT on any file error stopping from executing 'save'

Tags: azure-databricks, access-control, azure-data-lake-gen2

We have two different Azure cloud resource groups, RG1 and RG2, where RG1 hosts the ADB_source of the data source, and RG2 hosts the ADB_sink & ADLS_sink(gen2) of the data sink.

**Use Case:**
We have a few delta tables in ADB_source (ACL enabled) where a list of users has Read access.
In the ADB_source workspace, we need to read the delta tables and write them into ADLS_sink as parquet for further processing at the sink.

**What's Available:**
We have a high concurrency cluster created in ADB_Source workspace, which -

- Allows only Python & SQL (dbutils.fs also restricted).
- Credential Passthrough is disabled.
- Has ACLs Enabled in spark config.
- Has mount point created to a container in ADLS_sink.
- Has no Admin Access to the cluster.

**Errors Observed:**
We could read the delta tables as expected and run action commands as long as they are in the ADB_source workspace. However, when we write that data into the ADLS_sink with `.save()`, we get the below error.

```
Py4JJavaError: An error occurred while calling o410.save. : java.lang.SecurityException: User does not have permission SELECT on any file. User does not have permission MODIFY on any file.
```

I would appreciate it if anyone could explain this and recommend additional security checks/accesses needed to implement the use case successfully.

Answer (score 0):

This is happening because ACL is enabled, please refer to the documentation below:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/databricks/kb/security/table-create-security-exception